# How to use MVC Authorize attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I just start to try using MVC, and notice about the authorize attribute to limit access to authenticated user. Unfortunately it doesn't seems to work for now.

Below is my code :

Web.config :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Login/Index" timeout="30"/>
</authentication>
```

Login Controller :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ValidateLogin(UserLogin userLog)
    {

        if (userLog.UserName != "admin" || userLog.Password != "admin")
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error Message", "Wrong Login Credentials.");
            return View("Index", userLog);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
    }
```

Home Controller :

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It will still block access after enter a correct login.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you validate the user but you don't actually log in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to expand your login method with the actual login by the authenticationmanager:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ValidateLogin(UserLogin userLog)
{
    if (userLog.UserName != "admin" || userLog.Password != "admin")
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Error Message", "Wrong Login Credentials.");
        return View("Index", userLog);
    }

    // Signing in the user will make the Authorize attribute work! 
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE**?:
I've heart about FormsAuthentication, but not used it so far, maybe that's an option for you, but the AuthenticationManager is so easy to use!

Login:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

Logout:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
I still not sure what actually Authorize checking to allow access ?
Is there any other way which not using AuthenticationManager, like our own custom login validation ?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should look for a custom authorize attribute then?

Comment: Hi, so in order to authenticate user in MVC and use Authorize attribute we must use AuthenticationManager and cannot use something like cookie ?
Thank you.